# Save data to tinydb from android studio app

Tags: android, database, android-studio, document-database, tinydb

I have not used tinydb before. I am trying to insert some data to tinydb database using the android app.
I have checked many videos and blogs but still confused about how to use it.
How can I create a database and insert values from the app?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use firebase to insert some data, you can learn more rapidly because there are a lots of resources for firebase

Comment: My supervisor asked me to use tinydb